# Packages have unmet dependencies (1ubuntu1 vs 1ubuntu1k1)?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, libpng

While installing dependency packages I ran into this problem:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpng12-dev : Depends: libpng12-0 (= 1.2.54-1ubuntu1) but 1.2.54-1ubuntu1k1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

So, what the difference between **1ubuntu1** and **1ubuntu1k1** as shown above. I checked Synaptic package manager and only saw the latter, which is also my currently installed version. Based on the prompt, should I go uninstall the first version and install again the second one?

It's Ubuntu 16.04 by the way.

Edit:

Okay, `apt-cache policy libpng12-0` throws me this:

`libpng12-0:
  Installed: 1.2.54-1ubuntu1k1
  Candidate: 1.2.54-1ubuntu1k1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.54-1ubuntu1k1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.2.54-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Is that expected as normal?

Comment: When I went on to attempt to uninstall it, Synaptic told me that there were so many packages to be affected, and I felt there could be so much as risk to make this move. What should I do now? :(

Comment: Please edit your question to add the output of `apt-cache policy libpng12-0`.

Comment: Just updated the post as you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `libpng12-0` currently installed on your system is `1.2.54-1ubuntu1k1`. I have no idea where this version is coming from, and indeed it is not provided by any repository currently enabled on your system. Probably, either you have installed this version manually (by downloading it as a DEB package), or it was provided by a repository that used to be enabled and is now disabled.

In any case, the current version in the official Ubuntu 16.04 repositories is `1.2.54-1ubuntu1`, and other packages expect to see that version. Thus you should install version `1.2.54-1ubuntu1`, which you can do with

```
sudo apt install libpng12-0=1.2.54-1ubuntu1
```

Comment: Yea, that magic command made that switch successfully, albeit the output suggesting "downgrade" somehow. Thank you for your great help, and I wish you a cracking day :)

Comment: Yes, `1.2.54-1ubuntu1k1` is a higher version number than `1.2.54-1ubuntu1`, so when you revert to `1.2.54-1ubuntu1` you are technically downgrading the package.